# Aplicativo Desktop + DB Online (Hospedagem)

Tags: banco-de-dados, delphi, segurança

Boa tarde,

Galera, minha dúvida é a seguinte, na minha conexão de uma aplicativo desktop com banco de dados online:

1ª pergunta: Qual a melhor maneira de permanecer seguro a conexão realizada com o servidor de hospedagem?

2ª pergunta: Quais os riscos que irei correr e quais são as medidas que deveria tomar para eliminar ou diminuir esses riscos?

3ª pergunta: Tenho estas preocupações: Corrompimento de dados, invasões, queda de conexões e perca de dados. O que posso fazer para previnir este tipo de problema?

O meu aplicativo é feito em Delphi e meu banco de dados é Online (Servidor de Hospedagem).

Comment: Normalmente você não acessa o Banco no aplicativo desktop. O certo é acessar um serviço web, com autenticação etc. É muito dificil dizer qual a melhor técnica sem saber os detalhes do seu aplicativo, mas nunca se deve expor o banco de dados diretamente.

Comment: Exatamente isso que comente com meu chefe, mas como é aquele tipo de pessoa que quer o que pede, então pelo menos posso tentar diminuir os riscos de acesso.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bom, vamos por ordem.

---

**1**: Como manter a comunicação segura: acessando diretamente o banco pelo seu aplicativo, não tem como (explicação abaixo). Como seria feita essa comunicação de forma segura: um serviço web no servidor do banco de dados, expondo chamadas de alto nível, com autenticação etc.

---

**2**: Riscos:

**2.1**: O seu banco de dados deve ter usuário/senha. Isso de forma alguma significa segurança através de uma rede. Pense assim: seu aplicativo precisa manter essas informações. Qualquer um com acesso ao aplicativo poderia extrair esses dados e comprometer o Banco. Você poderia limitar os IPs que acessam o banco, mas isso reduz pouco o problema.

**2.2**: Se o seu aplicativo acessa o banco diretamente, um erro no aplicativo poderia comprometer os dados. A integridade deve ser mantida o mais próximo possível do banco de dados.

**2.3**: Se o seu aplicativo acessa o banco de dados diretamente, não há nada entre os dois. Isso significa que você está expondo um banco de dados que aceita qualquer comando, qualquer instrução.

---

**3**: Sinceramente não tenho experiência em uma arquitetura onde o aplicativo desktop acessa diretamente o banco. Além da segurança para acesso, talvez com VPN, é imprescindível usar stored procedures no banco de dados para expor somente chamadas completas. Jamais expor o banco de dados de forma aberta.

---

Outras vantagens de uma camada de abstração (web service):

1. O serviço envia/recebe dados de mais alto nível do aplicativo, o que reduz comunicação clente/servidor. O web service está no mesmo servidor que o banco de dados, e todas as chamadas e consultas intermediárias ficam locais no servidor. Lembre-se: você paga pelos dados que entram e saem do servidor...
2. Se você precisa mudar o banco de dados, pode mudar o web service e manter tudo funcionando. Será possível atualizar imediatamente todos os aplicativos clientes? O web service você controla, e pode atualizar, oferecendo os mesmos métodos para os clientes, que nem vêm a alteração.
3. Parecido com o item 1, a performance web service-banco de dados é muito maior que cliente-banco de dados. Ciclos de consulta-atualização rápidas se mantidas no mesmo servidor podem levar minutos se houver ida e volta pro cliente.
4. Se uma chamada tiver potencial para alterar muitos registros, você aceita que esses registros sejam enviados para o cliente, atualizados e devolvidos ao servidor? E se cada trip levar 30 segundos?

Comment: Basicamente a forma mais indicada de fazer uma conexão com banco de dados hospedado é via WebService.

Comment: o que me diz, por meio do Cpanel configurar o IP da empresa, e por meio de vpn conectar o sistema ao ip da empresa, melhora um pouco mais?

Comment: Isso reduz o problema de segurança, mas e a quantidade de dados, tempo de ida e volta, e o que acontece se o cliente perder a conexão no meio de uma chamada?

Comment: Eu não sei como te informar como securizar isso, por isso não considero o que ecrevi como resposta completa. Tentei te desencorajar a fazer da forma que você perguntou, esperemos que alguém possa te informar como fazer do jeito que precisa de forma mais segura.

Comment: Na verdade, eu estou desencorajado a fazer isso desde o início, só fiz a pergunta no fórum por que meu chefe insistiu sobre a pesquisa, mesmo eu tendo dito que não é uma boa prática e ninguém faria isso. Indiquei o WebService pq é a forma mais segura que eu encontrei até agora, sei que há outras, mas mesmo assim, é cabeça dura o suficiente para me fazer perguntar coisas inúteis sobre coisas que eu já sei. Indo contra os princípios da segurança de dados.

Comment: Exato... eu postei mais no sentido de te dar munição se quiser debater isso.

Comment: Show de bola, muito obrigado. :D